# adaptor for 1994 Mazda B2300 P/U

Tags: engine

My engine light comes off and on, I bought a DIAGNOSTIC SCAN TOOL (CAN OBDll) to check the engine light, as per Mazda book it shows in the diagram from my eec test plug to connect system selector tool 49-b019-9a0 to the data link connector. Then connect self diagnosis check tool 49-h018-9a1 to the system selector and a ground. My new tool has 16 pins where can I find and buy the proper tools that I need to diagnose this problem. Help would be greatly appreciated and if you have these tools I would

Answer (score 2):

The Mazda B series trucks are rebadged Ford Rangers. In 94 the Rangers were still OBDI (1).

To read the codes and look at the data you need something like this. 
[http://www.amazon.com/INNOVA-3140-OBD2-OBD1-Scan/dp/B000R3SNJU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000R3SNJU)

To just read codes you need something like this, it's cheap but a pain the but to use. [http://www.amazon.com/Actron-CP9015-Ford-Code-Scanner/dp/B0006V2BGY](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006V2BGY)